# Undefined reference to cmph functions even after installing cpmh library

Tags: header-files, undefined-reference, gcc4, perfect-hash

I am using gcc 4.4.3 on ubuntu. I installed cmph library tools 0.9-1 using command

sudo apt-get install libcmph-tools

Now, when I tried to compile example program vector_adapter_ex1.c , gcc is able to detect cmph.h library in its include file but is showing multiple errors like

vector_adapter_ex1.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `cmph_io_vector_adapter'
vector_adapter_ex1.c:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to`cmph_config_new'
vector_adapter_ex1.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `cmph_config_set_algo'
vector_adapter_ex1.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to`cmph_config_set_mphf_fd'

even though, these are all defined in the source code of the cmph library.

Could anyone tell the error that might have occurred or suggest an alternate method to go about building minimal perfect hash functions.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound lame, but have you linked with libcmph.la?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `gcc $(pkg-config --libs cmph) vector_adapter_ex1.c` assuming the library is installed. This will link you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the cmph library while compiling. 
`gcc <file name> -lcmph` will link the cmph library. Additionally you can specify the directory where to search the library for, using -L option.